# apache2 cant load images on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="a.jpg" alt = "Al Sheik" width="300px" height="300px" />
</body>
</html>
```

The above code cant display image that I was referencing. I was wondering what I was doing wrong? and below is the permissions of the folders and files.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pipi pipi 100726 Oct 12 16:14 a.JPG
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pipi pipi   2475 Oct 12 18:41 class.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 pipi pipi   4096 Oct 13 15:14 image
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pipi pipi  11321 Sep 28 18:38 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pipi pipi    431 Oct 13 15:40 index.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pipi pipi    157 Oct 12 10:50 me.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pipi pipi    447 Oct 12 15:00 my.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pipi pipi   2475 Oct 12 18:55 new.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pipi pipi    316 Oct  8 10:41 test.php
```

Comment: There is no `q.jpg` in the folder listing.

Comment: aww sorry... I copied the wrong code... If I run the HTML file in a browser on my desktop it runs without problems... But when I transfer it to the html folder in /var/www/ then I get blank image placeholder... and I have corrected what you were refering to @FlorianDiesch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's case sensitive.

If your picture is called `a.JPG` you need to write exactly that in your HTML

```
<img src="a.JPG" alt = "Al Sheik" width="300px" height="300px" />
```